# Can not get sound over HDMI in Kubuntu 9.10

Tags: audio, hdmi, nvidia-geforce, kubuntu

I have used a [HDMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI) cable to connect my LCD (which is connected with my speakers) with my [Nvidia 275 GTX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_200_Series) graphics card. I can not get the sound output to work. The hardware itself is working probably - I tested it under Windows.

Currently I am running [Kubuntu 9.10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubuntu#Releases) 64 with Nvidia 190.53. The sound output worked fine before I installed the HDMI connection.

(German output - I can change it, if you tell me how :))

Output of `aplay -l`:

```
**** Liste von PLAYBACK Geräten ****
Karte 0: Intel [HDA Intel], Gerät 0: ALC889A Analog [ALC889A Analog]
  Untergeordnete Geräte: 1/1
  Untergeordnetes Gerät '0: subdevice #0
Karte 0: Intel [HDA Intel], Gerät 1: ALC889A Digital [ALC889A Digital]
  Untergeordnete Geräte: 1/1
  Untergeordnetes Gerät '0: subdevice #0
```

Output of `aplay -L`:

```
front:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC889A Analog
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC889A Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC889A Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC889A Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC889A Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC889A Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC889A Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
```

And I disabled mute in kmix an all channels :)

**Edit:**

Output of `lspci -v`:

```
...
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Giga-byte Technology Device a022                                      
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 22                                
        Memory at ea400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]                         
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2                                    
        Capabilities: [60] Message Signalled Interrupts: Mask- 64bit+ Queue=0/0 Enable-  
        Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00              
        Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel <?>                                          
        Capabilities: [130] Root Complex Link <?>                                        
        Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel                                                  
        Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel   
...
```

Output of `cat /proc/asound/version`:

```
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version 1.0.20.
```

Output of `lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel`:

```
snd_hda_intel          31880  2
snd_hda_codec          87584  2 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_pcm                93160  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_pcm_oss
snd                    77096  16 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm_oss,snd_mixer_oss,snd_pcm,snd_seq_oss,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
snd_page_alloc         10928  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
```

I think I am missing the something-hdmi module? Is there such a thing?

**Edit 2:**

I have updated alsa.

Output of `cat /proc/asound/version`:

```
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version 1.0.22.1.
Compiled on Mar 29 2010 for kernel 2.6.31-20-generic (SMP).
```

HDMI audo still does not work.